# Why isn't conjugate transpose used as a default sign for transposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, transpose

When I'm looking at definitions/articles, etc., for real matrices the sign for transposition is upperscore T, while when a defintion for complex matrices/vector spaces, the sign for transposition is upperscore * (conjugate transpose). As you can use either for real matrices, why isn't the * used everywhere? What is the purpose of "splitting" the definitons like that?

Comment: There are matrices over other fields...

Comment: One among many things, $A^T$ is a polynomial map in the entries of the matrix, therefore polynomial identities involving the transponse that for whatever reason are true in $\Bbb R$ end up being true in $\Bbb C$ and more or less everywhere else despite not there being an immediate link to the transponse conjugate.

Comment: Mnemonics. "T" stands for "transpose", so we use it.